# Angular project showing monochromatic page despite installing ngx-bootstrap and bootstrap

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

I am developing an angular project using Angular 14 and I installed ngx-bootstrap 9.0.0 and bootstrap 5.3.0, following the instructions to install bootstrap manually following the instructions in the page https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started. I have tried everything and the project generate a page monochromatic, the btn-primary and btn-info are not working. I also trued an installed  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0".

I was expecting that the buttons have color and the page. I used carousels template and it is also black.